# Subquery as table name in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm in a situation where I'm dynamically creating tables. I'm basically wondering if there is a way to use the result of a sub query as the table in a `INSERT INTO` statement.

I have a working solution that uses dynamic SQL and the table name, but for more complex inserts that could get very messy.

Here's an example of what I mean.

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT name 
             FROM sys.objects 
             WHERE object_id = 914102297)
```

Comment: Nope. If you are dynamically creating the tables you are inserting into dynamic SQL is the only way. You can use `OBJECT_NAME(914102297)` though.

Comment: @Martin I'm getting `Invalid object name 'OBJECT_NAME'` Do you think you could toss me an example?

Comment: @Jack - I meant instead of selecting the name from `sys.objects` but then I looked again and see you already have the name so ignore that bit! There are no solutions other than dynamic SQL or not creating tables dynamically.

Comment: I'm concerned that you are dynamically creating tables, that is normally a sign that there is a design problem.

Comment: @HLGEM I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)


set @Query = 'INSERT INTO ' + (SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = 914102297)
set @Query = @Query + ...
exec sp_executesql @query
```